# Shorthand lambda expression

Tags: c#, linq, lambda, expression

Just a question in general... I'm fine with using the longhand version but from an academic viewpoint, I'm curious...

Why does the shorthand ?: not compile. It does not know how to convert lambda expression to lambda expression.

```
            Func<int> idProp = (personIdProperty == null) ? 
                () => Person.UserAccountId : 
                () => Person.Id;
```

However, when I break it out into longhand, it works just fine.

```
            Func<int> idProp;
            if (personIdProperty == null)
                idProp = () => Person.UserAccountId;
            else
                idProp = () => Person.Id;
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please format your code and make your post more readable.

Answer (score 1):

I had never tried that before, but yes the lambdas could be many different types, if you explicitly cast the result then it'll work.

```
            Func<int> idProp = (personIdProperty == null) ? 
            (Func<int>) (() => Person.UserAccountId): 
            (() => Person.Id);
```

Answer (score 0):

To help with inference in this case, you can pass Func through a function.
This way you can even omit the explicit type definition of Func:

```
var idProp = (personIdProperty == null) ?
    Func(() => Person.UserAccountId) : 
    Func(() => Person.Id);

//...
private Func<T1> Func<T1>(Func<T1> f)
{
    return f;
}
```